# CSS opacity animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have 3 icons on my site that I would like to fade in with CSS opacity and I would like them to be hidden before the animation starts. The visibility of the icons needs to be hidden starting out, but where? Here is the code I have so far:

```
/* Animation keyframes for icons below carousel */
@-moz-keyframes icon-move {
 0%  {opacity: 0;}
 25% {opacity: 0.2;}
 50% {opacity: 0.4;}
 75% {opacity: 0.6;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes icon-move {
 0%  {opacity: 0;}
 25% {opacity: 0.2;}
 50% {opacity: 0.4;}
 75% {opacity: 0.6;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes icon-move {
 0% {opacity: 0;}
 25% {opacity: 0.2;}
 50% {opacity: 0.4;}
 75% {opacity: 0.6;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}
.icon {
 -webkit-animation-name: icon-move;
 -ms-animation-duration: 10s;
 animation-duration: 10s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count: 2;
 -ms-animation-iteration-count: 2;
 animation-iteration-count: 2;
}
```

Comment: `.icon { opacity: 0 }`?

Comment: @JakobSternberg Don't sound so sad about it :) A misunderstanding doesn't change the fact that you tried to help someone which is a great thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `opacity: 0` to your `.icon` class.

In order to make your icons stay visible after the animation, define also the following property: `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` in your `.icon` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Animation keyframes for icons below carousel */
@-moz-keyframes icon-fade {
 0%  {opacity: 0.1;}
 25% {opacity: 0.3;}
 50% {opacity: 0.5;}
 75% {opacity: 0.8;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes icon-fade {
 0%  {opacity: 0.1;}
 25% {opacity: 0.3;}
 50% {opacity: 0.5;}
 75% {opacity: 0.8;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes icon-fade {
 0% {opacity: 0.1;}
 25% {opacity: 0.3;}
 50% {opacity: 0.5;}
 75% {opacity: 0.8;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}
.icon {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-animation-name: icon-fade;
 -moz-animation-name: icon-fade;
 animation-name: icon-fade;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 15s;
 -moz-animation-duration: 15s;
 animation-duration: 15s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
 animation-delay: 1s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Comment: Changed to 20s duration and 3s delay.